# Punctuation before and within an adverb clause

Tags: punctuation, adverbs, commas, subordinate-clauses

I have a sentence which includes two independent elements connected by 'and' within an adverb clause.  Do I still place a comma before the and?

Ex:

Jett's dad died when he was seven and his little brother was three.

or

Jett's dad died when he was seven, and his little brother was three.

Comment: The adverb clause is 'when he was seven and his little brother was three.' Adding a comma in the middle merely confuses matters.

Comment: But when you get to 'Jett's dad died when he was seven, his sister was six, and his little brother was three.' the comma becomes a very useful tool.

Comment: I agree: leave it comma free unless you have a whole list of clauses, in which case you may apply the general comma rule for lists.

Comment: You better **not**, or it could possibly mean the elements are "independent" (they are **not**). Parse:  (Jett's dad died) (when) (he was seven and his little brother was three.)

Answer (score 0):

To add a comma to separate two things isn't *always* wrong.

> There are two reasons we could never work out:  you, and me.

...but if it's not necessary -- and it isn't in your example -- we have another famous principles about when to use commas:

> "If in doubt, leave it out."

As I browse the Internet looking for commentary on this, I generally find advice that commas should separate *three or more* items in a list.  I think this is always a correct option, and almost always the best one.  (But not always -- as in the previous sentence!)